# IntelliJ - (de)activate line limit stroke

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

Is there a way to (de)activate and change the color of the stroke, that indicates the line limit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Right Margin` to change the size of the margin.

`File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show right margin` to activate or deactivate the margin.

`File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Right margin` to change the margin's colour.

Comment: Color is changeable: _File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Right margin_

Comment: @Scriptim Oh, I didn't know that. I'll edit it into the answer, nice catch.